# Image thresholding with my own min-max value with python

Tags: python, image-processing, binary, minmax, image-thresholding

I have an image to threshold. But I dont want to classical methods. I have my own min and max threshold value. How can i apply this threshold values to my image and get a binary mask. For example min is 300 and max is 500 if my pixel value is between these I get 255 if not I get 0. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you working with grayscale values? How are you loading your images? What have you tried so far code wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using opencv, there's the cv2.inRange(img, min, max) function that does exactly that. If you want a library agnostic solution then you could iterate through your image and build the mask yourself by checking each individual pixel value against your bounds.